# c# Richtext box can not load rtf file while Microsoft word using that file

Tags: c#

i used a read stream to read an rtf file however it failed when this rtf file is opened by  Microsoft word.

is there anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to read a RTF file for a rich text box (has to be of type [System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx)) is like this:

```
myRichTextBox.LoadFile(myFilename);
```

But, because you have a lock on the file, you have to do it this way (credit to @slaks):

```
myRichTextBox.LoadFile(new FileStream(myFilename, FileAccess.Read, FileSharing.ReadWrite));
```

And to save it, simply call this function:

```
myRichTextBox.SaveFile(myFilename);
```

Comment: Remember to dispose of the filestream when you're done with it.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
```